# Why Can't I set the id on GridFS using an id from a related mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs

My app is using node 0.10.1, express 3.1.1, mongoose 3.6.4, mongo 2.4.1 and gridfs-stream 0.4.0.

I have set up mongoose and gridfs-stream with a share connection as follows:

```
/************* app.js ***************/
//Added this in edit to show setup of mongoose and gridfs-stream
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
global.conn = mongoose.createConnection(dbUri);
conn.once('open', function(){
    global.gfs = Grid(conn.db);
});
```

I'm trying to upload/download files using gridfs-stream. My upload looks like:

```
exports.uploadFile = function(req, res){
    var file = req.files.upload;
    var docId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.docId);
    var filename = req.query.ileName;
    var contentType = file.type;

    if(!file) return res.send({result: 'NO_FILE_UPLOADED'});

    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        _id: docId,
        filename: filename,
        mode: 'w',
        root: 'documents'
    });
 // more here but ommitted
 };
```

The docId is coming from the ObjectId of a mongo document.

The upload appears to work. I can see the uploaded file using the mongo console:

```
db.documents.files.findOne()
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5167604d1b63f2541400003d"),
   "filename" : "borrower1.fnm",
   "contentType" : "binary/octet-stream",
   "length" : 3473,
   "chunkSize" : 262144,
   "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-04-12T15:43:06.723Z"),
   "aliases" : null,
   "metadata" : null,
   "md5" : "04c85fe5e9ba0e798fd5eb90f1cb62be"
}
```

When I try to download the file, using the following:

```
exports.downloadFile = function(req, res){
    var docId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.docId);
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: docId});
    readstream.pipe(res);
};
```

The following error is thrown:

```
Error: 5167604d1b63f2541400003d does not exist
```

When I attempt to retrieve the file directly from the mongo console using the _id which appears to get stored in the gridfs db, it returns null. But if I attempt to retrieve the file using the filename, the mongo console retrieves the file.

Can the _id of a uploaded file in gridfs not be set using the _id of a related mongo document? If so, how is my code incorrect? If not, is there a way to have grid generate the id and get the assigned id back so I can store it in the related mongo document?

Thanks for your help!

Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because I found the answer when going through the source code of mongoose server.js and gridfs-stream.

You can use the ObjectId of a related document for the ObjectId of the stored file.

However, if you provide a "root" option on the upload, you'll need to use it to use it in the download code as well. Otherwise, mongoose assumes the collection is the base collection.

So this works:

```
exports.uploadFile = function(req, res){
    var file = req.files.upload;
    var docId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.docId);
    var filename = req.query.ileName;
    var contentType = file.type;

    if(!file) return res.send({result: 'NO_FILE_UPLOADED'});

    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        _id: docId,
        filename: filename,
        mode: 'w',
        root: 'documents'
    });
 // more here but ommitted
 };

exports.downloadFile = function(req, res){
    var id = gfs.tryParseObjectId(req.query.docId);
    //note that options now includes 'root'
    var options = {_id: id, root: 'documents'};
    try{
        gfs.createReadStream(options).pipe(res);
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to convert req.query.docId to ObjectId? If you are receiving value from query it will be string, so you need to convert it to ObjectId if this type of _id was used during upload.

```
exports.downloadFile = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query.docId);
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.docId)});
    readstream.pipe(res);
};
```

Comment: Seba, more on this. I changed both my upload and download code to try to convert the docId into an ObjectId (see edits above). I'm still having the same problem. I'm starting to think that I'm not even getting the files uploaded correctly. I think I'm going to try to use MongoDb's native drive to see if I can get it to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#using-with-mongoose) page, are you assigning the mongoose driver to it.

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(..);
conn.once('open', function () {
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo); //missing parameter

  // all set!
})
```

or

```
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;  //missing 

var conn = mongoose.createConnection(..);
conn.once('open', function () {
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);

  // all set!
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But no, I had added it. I didn't show it. I have edited my question to show what I added.